# Soap is not working in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, soap-api-v2

I am getting an error when using soap API:

> `Couldn't load from
>   'https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to
>   load external entity
>   "https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"`

I am using PHP Version 7.0.32

I have checked solutions in which suggested install **php_openssl.dll** extension on the server. Is it required in PHP 7? **openssl** extension is enabled.

Please suggest any solution!

Comment: Go to Enable System-> Configuration->Services-> Magento Core API -> WS-I Compliance & Enable WSDL Cache, tell me what you getting after this changes.

Comment: both are enabled

Comment: Did you check Log Error?

Comment: nothing in log error.

Comment: Did you get any console error?

Comment: what do you mean by console error? I am testing from magento root.

Comment: Chrome or Firefox browser console error

Comment: Try running your same script from a different server and let me know what you get

Comment: @Haim, it is working on another server